# convertir script de $.getJSON a $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

Tengo un problema estoy tratando de pasar una serie de script de $.getJSON a $.post:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //getdeails será nuestra función para enviar la solicitud ajax
    var getdetails = function(id){
        return $.getJSON( "index.php", { "id" : id });
    }

    //al hacer click sobre cualquier elemento que tenga el atributo data-user.....
    $('[data-user]').click(function(e){
        //Detenemos el comportamiento normal del evento click sobre el elemento clicado
        e.preventDefault();
        //Mostramos texto de que la solicitud está en curso
        $("#response-container").html("<p>Buscando...</p>");
        //this hace referencia al elemento que ha lanzado el evento click
        //con el método .data('user') obtenemos el valor del atributo data-user de dicho elemento y lo pasamos a la función getdetails definida anteriormente
        getdetails($(this).data('user'))
        .done( function( response ) {
            //done() es ejecutada cuándo se recibe la respuesta del servidor. response es el objeto JSON recibido
            if( response.success ) {

                var output = "<h1>" + response.data.message + "</h1>";
                //recorremos cada usuario
                $.each(response.data.users, function( key, value ) {
                    output += "<h2>Detalles del usuario " + value['ID'] + "</h2>";
                    //recorremos los valores de cada usuario
                    $.each( value, function ( userkey, uservalue) {
                        output += '<ul>';
                        output += '<li>' + userkey + ': ' + uservalue + "</li>";
                        output += '</ul>';
                    });
                });

                //Actualizamos el HTML del elemento con id="#response-container"
                $("#response-container").html(output);

                } else {
                //response.success no es true
                $("#response-container").html('No ha habido suerte: ' + response.data.message);
            }
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            $("#response-container").html("Algo ha fallado: " +  textStatus);
        });
    });
});
```

debido a las limitaciones a pasar "N" cantidades de caracteres por Get, en el intento de pasarlo a $.post tengo este codigo:

```
var getdetails = function(id){
    return $.post('index.php',{"id":id},"json");
}
```

pero me da un parseError y no tengo ni idea que estoy haciendo mal, ya que considero que solo era necesaria cambiar el metodo, den envio al servidor. me pueden ayudar a resolver esto manteniendo la idea?

Comment: Primeramente `$.post`  no regresa valores, adentro de los parámetros mandas una función callback que se ejecutará cuando el servidor te arroje respuesta, y la notación para el parámetro data normalmente va `{id : id]`

Comment: y la respuesta cual seria entonces???

Comment: Te recomiendo leas la guía de jQuery de post, ahí te pone ejemplos de cómo mandas tu función callback para manejar la respuesta del servidor https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ `$.post(url,data,function(resp){console.log(resp)})`

Comment: ok actualice el código para que tengas una mejor idea de que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Cambia la función a como la puso Camilo en su respuesta, y con eso ya no te dará problemas

Comment: me da error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analizando la forma en como tomas los datos de la respuesta de la función ajax, tendrás que usar diferidos para poder manejar la función `.done()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $def = $.Deferred();
    //getdeails será nuestra función para enviar la solicitud ajax
    var getdetails = function(id){
        $.post('personas.php',{id:id}, function(respuesta){
            $def.resolve(respuesta);
        }, "json");
        return $def;
    }

//al hacer click sobre cualquier elemento que tenga el atributo data-user.....
$('[data-user]').click(function(e){
    //Detenemos el comportamiento normal del evento click sobre el elemento clicado
    e.preventDefault();
    //Mostramos texto de que la solicitud está en curso
    $("#response-container").html("<p>Buscando...</p>");
    //this hace referencia al elemento que ha lanzado el evento click
    //con el método .data('user') obtenemos el valor del atributo data-user de dicho elemento y lo pasamos a la función getdetails definida anteriormente
    getdetails($(this).data('user'))
    .done( function( response ) {
        //done() es ejecutada cuándo se recibe la respuesta del servidor. response es el objeto JSON recibido
        if( response.success ) {

            var output = "<h1>" + response.data.message + "</h1>";
            //recorremos cada usuario
            $.each(response.data.users, function( key, value ) {
                output += "<h2>Detalles del usuario " + value['ID'] + "</h2>";
                //recorremos los valores de cada usuario
                $.each( value, function ( userkey, uservalue) {
                    output += '<ul>';
                    output += '<li>' + userkey + ': ' + uservalue + "</li>";
                    output += '</ul>';
                });
            });

            //Actualizamos el HTML del elemento con id="#response-container"
            $("#response-container").html(output);

            } else {
            //response.success no es true
            $("#response-container").html('No ha habido suerte: ' + response.data.message);
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        $("#response-container").html("Algo ha fallado: " +  textStatus);
    });
});
```

});

La variable $def no es más que una promesa (diferido) de jQuery que regresas en tu función getdetails, la cual al resolverse `resolve()` mandará ejecutar la función `done()` con todo el código que haya dentro de este mismo.

Comment: gracias amigo, el problema ahora es que no muestra los datos de las respuesta y se queda en `buscando`.... una ultima consulta, Existe alguna manera de mejorar mi script y que sea mas sencillo que esto.

Comment: parece que no funciona correctamente.

Comment: Imprime la variable respuesta dentro del `done()` es probable que el formato JSON lo regrese algo diferente a `$.getJSON` o tal vez haya algo mal con la función ajax de post

Comment: no imprime nada, no entra en el done ni en el fail. ta cabron... no hay feedback, o sera que hay que cambiarlo por success??

Comment: Trata cambiar como estába tu funcion original, el objeto mándalo como `{'id':id}` y luego imprime la variable respuesta pero dentro del `$.post`

Comment: Nada :( no hay respuesta , parece que se salta el  `getdetails($(this).data('user'))` puse un `console.log('paso 1')` al inicio del script y otro al final `console.log('paso 2')` y puse el que me indicaste dentro del post en la funcion  `$.post('index.php',{'id':id}, function(respuesta){
         console.log(respuesta);
            $def.resolve(respuesta);
        }, "json"); ` pero no me tira ninguna respuesta...

Comment: no me tira nada por la consola tampoco.

Comment: Perdona, es `index.php` o `personas.php`?

Comment: es index.php dejame corregirlo a mi tambien pero eso no es, yo lo tengo bien con las modificaciones que me has dicho ... sigue apuntando al archivo index.php

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67906/discussion-between-yikarus-and-francisco-nunez).

Answer (score 1):

Cuando en un `$.post` estás pasando el valor de `dataType` es obligatorio entonces que también ejecutes la función `success` que retorna los valores devueltos, sería algo así:

```
var getdetails = function(id){
    $.post('index.php',{id:id}, function(respuesta){
        return respuesta
    }, "json");
}
```

Aunque si no necesitas una función que retorne los valores puedes declararla como `null`:

```
var getdetails = function(id){
    $.post('index.php',{id:id}, null, "json");
}
```

Comment: puedes revisar mi acttualizacion agregue el script completo; con tus recomendaciones me sale: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Comment: El error era en tu `getdetails($(this).data('user')) .done( function( response ) {` pero ya @Yikarus a dado solución a ese error!